# Beginner:What do several parts of my code mean?

Tags: java, android, button

Because I'm an absolute beginner I have a really simple question but I can't help myself.Maybe they are too simple because I can't find the answer in forums, books or other internet paged. I do not get the meaning of some parts of my java code because i just knew the ''normal'' eclipse, and android is so different to that.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class Spritkostenactivity extends Activity
implements View.OnClickListener{


    private TextView textcosts;
    private TextView textcostsperson;

    private Button buttonnew;
    private Button buttonstop;
```

Are these elements (Button and TextView) objects, variables, attributes? How can I call them?

```
        buttonnew= (Button)     findViewById(R.id.buttonerneuteberechnung);
        buttonnew.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonstop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonschliessen);
        buttonstop.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now I put the element of the xml file in the "buttons". If they are objects, why don't I have to write something like "Button buttonnew=new ..." Because after that the Buttons start a Method, so do they need to be an object?
And what does the "this" mean. I read that it means the actual object, but what does the actual object mean?

```
  Double.parseDouble(liters)
```

My last question is about the method Double.parsedouble().
Can you say me for what the **Double**(.parsedouble) stands? Is it the classname that starts the method?

I'm really sorry that there are several questions in one post, but I think this is basic knowledge, and it wouldn't be necessary to post it in more questions.
I hope you can help me. Thank You!

Comment: @Juned Ahsan I read 3 books about android apps.. I just want to understand the most simple things that aren't explained in my books so well that I could understand it. I'm really sorry if this sounds dumb to you but I would be really grateful if you helped me.

Comment: @Vivian If you're having problems with the basics, you should start with the [tutorials from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).  Start with **Trails Covering the Basics**.

Comment: You are right. Most of your questions are about basic things. About *VERY* basic things. And that's exactly why you should read some java tutorials.

Comment: @Vivian There is no shame of asking basic questions ;) Everybody needs to start some time ! But I recon reading books and stuff isn't that...fun to do. I followed this course by Coursera. https://class.coursera.org/android-001/lecture. The lectures are free !! The bloke begins at the very start of Android programming :) Hope it helps ya out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button` and `TextView` are class names. When I type:

```
private Button myButton;
```

I create a reference to an object of type button that points to an empty address location.

If I then instantiate an object as follows:

```
myButton = new Button();
```

myButton will refer to a newly created `Button` object in the program's memory.

For android, or any Java Swing, `Button` objects simply mean buttons in your GUI interface. While `TextView` is a text field that displays.. you guessed it.. text.

---

In your case, the `Button` is something you already have in your XML file describing your GUI, so you point to that button in your object by using `findViewById(..)`.

Regarding `this`, it refers to an object of the class that you are in. So whenever I instantiate an object of type `Spritkostenactivity`, there will be a button listening to clicks on `this` object (any instance of `Spritkostenactivity`) due to the statement `buttonstop.setOnClickListener(this)`.

---

`Double` is the class name of the data type that holds a double-precision floating point number, `parseDouble` is a function that takes a string and formats it into a `double` number.

Comment: Thank you, this post was really helpful for me!